# JDBC Connect extracts incomplete table from VERTICA without warning

Tags: r, jdbc, odbc, vertica

I am only getting partial data set when I tried to import table from Vertica into R through JDBC connect. Interestingly, R Code ran fine without any warning but resulted in partial data set. I have a colleague who shares the similar experience while using RODBC connect to extract data from Vertica.
I appreciate for any insight on this issue. If this is an issue with Vertica, is there a way to signal Vertica to extend timeout period?  Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
library(RJDBC);
vDriver = JDBC(driverClass="com.vertica.jdbc.Driver", 
classPath="C:/Program Files/Aqua Data Studio 14.0 - 64bit/lib/drivers/vertica-jdk5-  6.0.1-0_JDBC.jar")


vconnect1 = dbConnect(vDriver, 
'jdbc:vertica://shr2-vrt-pro-vglb1.XXXXXXX.XX.XXX:5433/shr1_vrt_pro', 
'myusername', 'mypassword')

system.time(PredDSN<- dbGetQuery(vconnect1, "select distinct cid 
,product_type
from myDB.brd_CF_input_data_p1 as a
where a.purchase_order_calendar_dt<= date('09/27/2014') 
and a.purchase_order_calendar_dt>=date('09/27/2014')-(52*4*7)+1 "));
```

user  system elapsed 
  82.61    2.38  521.77

dim(PredDSN)
[1] 7796903       3

Query from Vertica shows otherwise: 
count
20709932

```
select count(*)
from myDB.brd_CF_input_data_p1
where purchase_order_calendar_dt<= date('09/27/2014')   
and purchase_order_calendar_dt>=date('09/27/2014')-(52*4*7)+1
```

My system info:

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit); RJDBC_0.2-4

Comment: Can you share the command you are using in R to import ? I see you are using Aqua Data Studio. I use ADS and it has native connectivity and you can import into Vertica easily

Comment: Isn't that ADS stands for Aqua Data Studio? I think RJDBC connect works fine. It was network drop-off and vertica connecion issue rather than the issue with RJDBC.

Comment: Yes ADS stands for Aqua Data Studio. Do you use a Generic JDBC connection with Aqua Data Studio ? Great to hear that your problem was resolved.